# Can Rasterio python package read/open rasters stored in a Geopackage?

Tags: python, raster, rasterio, geopackage

I've searched a lot and I couldn't find any code sample using rasterio to open rasters stored in a Geopackage.

If someone knows anything about this topic, I would be greateful if the knowledge could be shared.

Comment: It was me who asked this other question. I'd like to read a dem which is inside a geopackege with rasterio. Until now I haven't found out how.

Comment: In order to keep things focussed, its best to only ask one question per issue, asking it more than once can create issues on the site.

Comment: Answered in other question